# How to traverse a map in Go through reflection

Tags: dictionary, go, reflection

I am attempting to write a simple recursive function to traverse a structure in Go and look for a certain type however I am having a hard time dealing with a structure in a map and reflection

The example below illustrates the issue

https://play.golang.org/p/LxuInxyIIEG

I cannot call `v.MapIndex(key)` because I get an issue that it is not a pointer and I cannot address it either.

How do I deal with that?

Also when looking for a struct type by comparing v.Type, how do I make sure that I found the type regardless of whether it is a pointer or not (As I might want to call a function on it)? My code above compares to `reflect.TypeOf(Second{})` but I would also like to cover a pointer of Second. Would adding the check for `reflect.TypeOf(&Second{})` suffice?

Comment: Can you better explain what you're trying to do? Map values are never addressable., but they might already be a pointer value. Why do you need to ensure that you're traversing everything through a pointer?

Comment: Hi. I have updated the code above to better reflect the issue. My struct consists of pointers of that struct and I want to find all references of that type (what I work with I don't care much but the struct consists of Pointers thus why I look for pointers). The issue is that it seems that getting the map value returns the concrete type even though it is a map of pointers. I am unsure how to go about that. Ultimately, what is not shown in the code is that the Second struct has a method on it I am going to call through reflection but felt it is irrelevant to the issue at hand

Comment: It is generally better to include any relevant code in your question than to link to it somewhere else. Including a play.golang.org link is great but it should augment the question rather than contain part of the question.

Comment: @ByteFlinger: the updated example works, so I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: @JimB Actually it does not. Noticed that it prints out that it finds the Second struct only once. it should print it twice but the second time is not printed because even though it is a map of `*Second`, it comes in as `Second` thus not matching the check of `reflect.TypeOf(&Second)`.  I am just a bit confused on why the check doesn't work

Comment: You need to show what you expect it to do in order for us to know what's not working. You can't match `&Second{}` because right before that you call `Indirect()`. Do you want something like this?: https://play.golang.org/p/PNWQM-PDBxf

Comment: Yes. That works well, thank you